# How do I modify this SQL Query to fetch information located in another table?

Tags: sql-server, join

I’m using SQL Server 2014 and I have a simple query that uses 3 tables to give me the following ouput relating to reservations made by guests:

Query looks like this:

```
USE MyDatabase

SELECT a.ResID, a.Name, a.Property, c.ArrivalDate,c.DepartureDate,c.ConfNum, 
d.CHAR07, c.StatusCode,c.CreatedOn, c.UpdatedBy, c.CreatedBy
FROM GuestStaySummary a
     left join GuestNameInfo b on b.ResID = a.ResID
     left join reservationstay c on c. ResID = a. ResID 
WHERE a.PrimaryGuest = '+'
```

Output is as follows:

```
ResID      Property  Name      ArrivalDate   DepartureDate  ConfNum    StatusCode  CreatedOn    UpdatedBy  CreatedBy 
125         ABC      Jones      2015-08-20    2015-08-27    659874      CONFIRMED   2015-03-10     AP01      AP01
```

Due to an application upgrade on the system, all reservations were cancelled and re-created. As such, the entry above became as follows:

```
ResID      Property  Name      ArrivalDate   DepartureDate  ConfNum   StatusCode   CreatedOn    UpdatedBy  CreatedBy 
125         ABC      Jones      2015-08-20    2015-08-27    659874     CANCELED    2015-03-10       R5      AP01
358         ABC      Jones      2015-08-20    2015-08-27    742651     CONFIRMED   2015-05-15       R5      AP01
```

The original `ResID` 125 now has a `StatusCode` as ‘CANCELED’ and it has been re-created with a NEW `ResId` and NEW `ConfNum`.

The original `CreatedOn` (that is 2015-03-10) of the `ResId` 125 (now Res ID 358) is very important for my analytics purposes. In other words, I need to link `ResID` 358’s `CreatedOn` with 2015-03-10 instead of its new `CreatedOn` which is 2015-05-15.

The only way to link these 2 entries is by making use of the “original” `ConfNum` which has been stored in a table called `P5RESERVATIONSTAY` in a column called `CHAR07`.

I have modified my query as follows to retrieve the list of all “canceled” reservations and their equivalent “new” reservations:

```
USE MyDatabase

SELECT a.ResID, a.Name, a.Property, c.ArrivalDate,c.DepartureDate,c.ConfNum, 
d.CHAR07 AS ‘Original ConfNum’, c.StatusCode,c.CreatedOn, c.UpdatedBy,     c.CreatedBy
FROM GuestStaySummary a
     left join GuestNameInfo b on b.ResID = a.ResID
     left join reservationstay c on c. ResID = a. ResID 
     left join P5RESERVATIONSTAY d on d.RSY_RESERVATIONSTAYID = a.ResID
     left join P5RESERVATIONSTAY d2 on d2.CHAR07 = c.ConfNum
 WHERE b.PrimaryGuest = '+'
```

The output is now as follows:

```
ResID      Property   Name      ArrDate      DepDate      ConfNum     Original ConfNum      StatusCode     CreatedOn    UpdatedBy  CreatedBy 
125         ABC      Jones      2015-08-20    2015-08-27    659874         NULL               CANCELED    2015-03-10       R5      AP01
358         ABC      Jones      2015-08-20    2015-08-27    742651         659874             CONFIRMED   2015-05-15       R5      AP01
```

It does the job but I am faced with some additional work in Excel with a VLOOKUP to fetch the original CreatedOn.

I would like my SQL Query to give me the following output:

```
ResID  Property  Name    ArrDate     DepDate      ConfNum     Original ConfNum    StatusCode     CreatedOn     OriginalCreatedOn  UpdatedBy  CreatedBy 

 358     ABC      Jones  2015-08-20    2015-08-27    742651       659874             CONFIRMED    2015-05-15       2015-03-10        R5        AP01
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Not sure why you're using all left joins. Once you filter on `PrimaryGuest` you've effectively got an inner join anyway. Also you join to `d2` but don't use any of its columns and I really don't see why you're using that table twice in the first place.

Comment: I joined to d2 with the logic that it would have helped me to fetch the original CreatedOn and match it with its "new" reservation but I was stuck at this level of my coding. So, I left it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you really just need to join back to `reservationstay` again? I think the inner joins will take care of including only the correct canceled and re-created rows but I'm not 100% sure since I don't know what other data you've got in there.

```
SELECT
    gss.ResID, gss.Property, gss.Name, rs.ArrivalDate, rs.DepartureDate, rs.ConfNum,
    p5rs.CHAR07 as "Original ConfNum", rs.StatusCode, rs.CreatedOn,
    rsorg.CreatedOn as "Original CreatedOn", rs.UpdatedBy, rs.CreatedBy
FROM
    GuestStaySummary as gss
    inner join GuestNameInfo     as gni   on gni.ResID = gss.ResID
    inner join reservationstay   as rs    on rs.ResID = gss.ResID 
    inner join P5RESERVATIONSTAY as p5rs  on p5rs.RSY_RESERVATIONSTAYID = gss.ResID 
    inner join reservationstay   as rsorg on rsorg.ConfNum = p5rs.CHAR07
WHERE
    gni.PrimaryGuest = '+'
```

Comment: Thanks. I will test your solution on Monday. I don't have access to the server right now for testing it!